# Detecting changes to a DependencyProperty by my own code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

My control has a property that maps to a private variable. When the property is set, I also need to store a certain other variable. When the private variable of the property is set by my own control code, this special handling must not occur. All good.

I now need to refactor that to a DependencyProperty. I only have a change handler here, and all (also internal) accesses to that property must go through the DependencyProperty framework. There is no more private variable that I could set directly. Every change done by my own code now looks exactly the same as changes from external sources like the user of the control or DataBinding.

In my property change handler, how can I determine whether a value change came from my code or somewhere else?

This is the old code:

```
private DateTime selectedTime;
private int intendedDay;

public DateTime SelectedTime
{
    get { return selectedTime; }
    set
    {
        selectedTime = value;
        intendedDay = selectedTime.Day;
    }
}
```

In this code, I can set `selectedTime` directly, not affecting `intendedDay` which must only be set when `SelectedTime` is assigned a new value altogether from the outside, or when I see fit in my control.

The DependencyProperty only allows me to detect any changes:

```
public static DependencyProperty SelectedTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedTime",
    typeof(DateTime),
    typeof(DateTimeTextBox),
    new PropertyMetadata(SelectedTimeChanged));

public DateTime SelectedTime
{
    get { return (DateTime) GetValue(SelectedTimeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedTimeProperty, value); }
}

private static void SelectedTimeChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    DateTimeTextBox control = (DateTimeTextBox) obj;
    // This must not happen where I previously assigned the private variable:
    control.intendedDay = control.SelectedTime.Day;
}

private int intendedDay;
```

So when I would previously assign the private variable, I can now only set the dependency property, which will also change `intendedDay`.

Comment: StackFrame is no option, it fails too easily and it too expensive. I have no problem setting both variables in my control when needed. The problem is that I need to be able to change just one. But when the other is automatically updated as well, they're both glued together.

Comment: I can propose to use an ugly solution with private flag and special SetSelectedTime method, that uses this flag to control `SelectedTimeChanged`. But it is kludgy and may lead to some concurrency issues.

Comment: The private flag may be ugly, but is inevitable. I came up with an InternalSetValue method that sets the flag, then calls SetValue, then clears the flag.

Comment: Ah, you mean the `private bool isUpdating` that is set `true` around setting the dependency property, and evaluated in the change handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Clemens explained in his comment, I added a private variable that indicates whether I am currently updating that property from my own code. I set it to true whenever I want to suppress external value change handling, and false afterwards. So I can distinguish whether it was an internal or external value change.

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap your dependency property in a normal property? Setting the property will still set the dependency property and setting the private one will not set the intendedDay value.

```
private DateTime selectedTime
{
    get { return (DateTime) GetValue(SelectedTimeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedTimeProperty, value); }
}

public DataTime SelectedTime
{
    get { return selectedTime; }
    set
    {
        selectedTime = value;
        intendedDay = selectedTime.Day;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that with dependency properties, you have no access to the actual data storage. (The CLR property is just a shortcut for your code. Other methods don't need to use it.) And this actual data storage can be changed through a binding – directly with no layer in between. This must always set `intendedDay` as well. Now, how can my own control code change the property value without changing `intendedDay`?

Comment: Ah, I see. So if SetValue must always set the intendedDay if called by anything but this then we have an interesting problem. Let me give it some thought

Comment: Reading your comments, it looks like you've come up with a working solution. I'm not aware of any CLR magig that allows you to determine the caller of the SetValue method without using reflection and the stackframe = slow and ugly.

Comment: I remember there's something like a shutdown reason when Windows shuts down, or when an application quits. There might have been a similar "update reason" for dependency properties.